# Conditional Statement Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, conditional-statements

This is just an example from notes (Python Objects Basics)

```
class Cow():

  noise = 'moo!'

  def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color
    print "This cow is " + self.color

  def make_noise(self):
    print self.noise

  def set_color(self, new_color):
    self.color = new_color

  def get_color(self):
    return self.color

  def __cmp__(self, other):
    if self.color == other.color:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def __str__(self):
    return self.color + ' ' + self._noise

blue_cow = Cow('blue')
red_cow = Cow('red')

blue_cow.make_noise()

print red_cow == blue_cow

blue_cow.set_color('red')
print red_cow == blue_cow
```

This the output after running:

```
moo!
True
False
```

What I didn't understood is why (3 line from last)

```
print red_cow == blue_cow
```

is giving True while it's suppose to give False(my view) since red_cow has red color and blue_cow has blue color

And the last line two lines

```
blue_cow.set_color('red')
print red_cow == blue_cow
```

And the last line why it executes to False while in my opinion I expect it to execute to True

Comment: Try using `__eq__` instead of `__cmp__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `__eq__`, or you can change your method to actually compare the strings using [`cmp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp).

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.color, other.color)
```

This allows all the other comparison operations to work.

```
print red_cow == blue_cow # False
print blue_cow < red_cow # True
print sorted([red_cow, blue_cow]) # [blue moo!, red moo!]

blue_cow.color = 'red'
print red_cow == blue_cow # True
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `__cmp__`, try using `__eq__` and it will work (tested).

Answer (score 0):

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**cmp**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

> Called by comparison operations if rich comparison (see above) is not
>   defined. **Should return a negative integer** if self < other, **zero** if
>   self =other, a **positive integer** if self > other. If no **cmp**(),
>   **eq**() or **ne**() operation is defined,

If you change `__cmp__` to return 0 if equal, and non zero if not equal it will also work.  On python 2.7.X